# Remove lines from file containing a substring

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove some lines from a file.
In specific I need to remove all lines **containing** the substring: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm`

I tried:

`sed -i -e "/export JAVA_HOME=\"\/usr\/lib\/jvm*/d" file`

and

`sed -i -e "/export JAVA_HOME=\"\/usr\/lib\/jvm/d" file`

but those don't remove the line I have in the `file` that is:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-8-amd64/jre/`

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation mark from your pattern, since it doesn't appear in the line you want to remove:

```
sed -i -e "/export JAVA_HOME=\"\/usr\/lib\/jvm/d" file
#                            ^^ remove this
```